# memory management for an immutable data model

Tags: c++

I've written a little toy data model, which uses a `std::set` to unique instances. This may be called either the flyweight pattern, or [hash-consing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) (though, technically, I'm not yet using a hash table).

```
#include <set>
#include <cassert>

enum Color { Red, Green, Blue };

struct Shape {

  // Set the color, return a new shape.
  virtual const Shape* color(Color) const = 0;

};

template<class T>
const T* make_shape(T value) {

  struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const T* a, const T* b) const {
      return *a < *b;
    }
  };

  static std::set<const T*, cmp > values;

  auto iter = values.find(&value);

  if(iter != values.end()) {
    return *iter;
  }

  auto p = new T(value);
  values.insert(p);
  return p;

}

struct Circle : public Shape {
  Color c = Red;
  virtual const Shape* color(Color c) const {
    Circle r;
    r.c = c;
    return make_shape(r);
  }
  bool operator<(const Circle& rhs) const { return c < rhs.c; }
};
```

Here's my test code. Notice how the first two lines return the same pointer, so these semantics are different from normal allocation via `new` or `make_shared`.

```
void test_shape() {

  auto s0 = make_shape(Circle{});
  auto s1 = make_shape(Circle{});

  // Structurally equivalent values yield the same pointer.
  assert(s0 == s1);

  // Color is red by default, so we should get the same pointer.
  auto s2 = s0->color(Red);

  assert(s2 == s0);

  // Changing to Green gives us a different pointer.
  auto s3 = s0->color(Green);

  assert(s3 != s0);

  printf("done\n");

}

int main() {
    test_shape();
}
```

Right now, the shapes are simply leaked. That is to say that once a client of this data model no longer has a pointer to a `Shape`, that shape is not deallocated (consider the `set` to be weak references that should be broken).

So I'd like to use `shared_ptr` to manage my objects, because it seems simple (also open to other ideas, but **I don't want to add dependencies, like boost**).

But I'm having a little trouble with `shared_ptr`. I've tried updating the `std::set` to store `std::weak_ptr<const T>` with a comparison using `owner_before`.

I need a `shared_ptr` to look up the object in the set. But that would require newing an object, and part of the point here is to be able to quickly get an existing structurally equal object.

**Update**

I also tried keeping the `set` as raw pointers, and using the `shared_ptr` deleter to remove elements. Alas, that requires me to use `shared_from_this` which seems to balk, though I'm not exactly sure why:

```
shape.cpp:30:16: error: member reference base type 'Circle *const' is not a
      structure or union
    return iter->shared_from_this();
           ~~~~^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You can write a SFINAE `operator<` that will apply to classes that fulfill a certain concept that you can define (usually, either derivation from an empty "tag" base class, or presence of some member).

Comment: @KubaOber can I use that to automatically define lexicographical comparison on my structs?

Comment: Why are you `new`ing your elements and only storing references? Your lifetime goals are not understandable. Don't further explain your implementation approach, but your original problem. Why can you store them in the container? If not why not make a clean container class.

Comment: @freakish I've removed that commentary, which may just be misleading.

Comment: @freakish If you consider that the `set` is storing weak references, then they are effectively leaked. Think about what a client of a data model library would want. You'd want to make shapes, and when you are done with them, they are cleaned up. That can be done via reference counting.

Comment: @freakish Notice how the semantics are different from a simple shared pointer allocation in the test. Two calls to `make_shared` would not return the same pointer.

Comment: @Taylor so basically whenever someone "constructs" an object with the same parameters (or "equal") then the mechanism is supposed to return an already cached object. Right, so you are simply implementing a cache. Your weak_ptr idea is ok (again: this **is not** a leak). What you need is a cleanup mechanism. Like for example a separate thread that will periodically rebuild the cache by removing dead weak_ptrs.

Comment: There can be various ways how to solve that problem. But without knowing the exact lifetime constraints/flow and ownership patterns it is hard to tell.

Comment: @t.niese What am I missing? it seems so simple.

Comment: @Taylor don't you know that there are only two hard things in computer science? Naming and cache invalidation. :)

Comment: @freakish and deciphering template errors ;-)

Comment: @Taylor jokes aside, don't you like the idea of a separate cleaner thread? You can even utilize a conditional variable to wake it up on shared_ptr destruction.

Comment: If it would be simple you would already have a solution ;). You could have stacked allocation pools, separated allocation pools, timed- or probability-based gc, ... . It all depends on how many allocation deallocations you are dealing with,  in which order allocations and deallocations happens if they can be grouped.

Comment: @t.niese Posted my solution below. Seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative solution is for your clients to use a factory that owns the objects it hands out. This way your clients can use plain pointers to refer to objects.

Once the client is done, it can dispose of the factory along with all the objects.

In addition, may be, have the factory reference counted, or keep a `shared_ptr` to it.

Comment: Oh, one problem is that there are a lot of ephemeral objects generated during user interactions. So it could use up a lot of memory before the factory is cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code. Turns out I'm just not very good at programming and didn't realize I had to deref something.

Basic approach is that the `shared_ptr` deleter removes the raw pointer from the `set`.

```
#include <set>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

enum Color { Red, Green, Blue };

struct Shape;
struct Circle;

struct Shape : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Shape> {

    virtual ~Shape() = default;

    // Set the color, return a new shape.
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Shape> color(Color) const = 0;

};

template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<Shape> make_shape(T value) {

    struct cmp {
        bool operator()(const T* a, const T* b) const {
            return *a < *b;
        }
    };

    static std::set<T*, cmp> values;

    auto iter = values.find(&value);

    if(iter != values.end()) {
        return (*iter)->shared_from_this();
    }

    auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(value), [](T* p) {
        printf("deleting %p\n", (void*)p);
        values.erase(p); delete p;
    });
    values.insert(ptr.get());
    return ptr;

}

struct CircleCount {
    static int count;

    CircleCount() { ++count; }
    CircleCount(const CircleCount&) { ++count; }
    ~CircleCount() { --count; }
};

int CircleCount::count;

struct Circle : public Shape {
    CircleCount count;
    Color c = Red;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Shape> color(Color c) const {
        Circle r;
        r.c = c;
        return make_shape(r);
    }
    bool operator<(const Circle& rhs) const { return c < rhs.c; }
};

void test_shape() {

    {
        auto s0 = make_shape(Circle{});
        auto s1 = make_shape(Circle{});

        assert(s0 == s1);

        auto s2 = s0->color(Red);

        assert(s2 == s0);

        auto s3 = s0->color(Green);

        assert(s3 != s0);
    }

    // All circles should be cleaned up.
    printf("circles: %d\n", CircleCount::count);
    assert(CircleCount::count == 0);

    printf("done\n");

}

int main() {
    test_shape();
}
```

**Update**

I made this into something generic, which is up for code review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224433/generic-flyweighting-function)

Comment: IMHO - but I can't confirm it right now  - you need to add `virtual ~Shape() = default;`  (or at least to Circle?) otherwise it might be UB.

Comment: Also note that this solution is not thread safe (although the original code is no thread safe as well).

Comment: And a bit nitpicking about the `No use of weak_ptr :)`, `[...]A common implementation for enable_shared_from_this is to hold a weak reference (such as std::weak_ptr) to this[...]` ([std::enable_shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)), so it is a hidden weak pointer. But yes you only need to lock one weak pointer per insert instead of `values.size()` weak pointers, which is a huge benefit.

Comment: @t.niese Don't need the virtual dtor because the deleter knows the derived type.

Comment: @Taylor if you use `make_shape` exclusively to construct the shapes, then this is true. But nothing in your code prevents one from creating the instance without `make_shape`. So either you make this impossible, you use virtual, or document it and hope that everyone reads the documentation.

Comment: @t.niese I'm the only developer. That said, how can I prevent creating an instance without `make_shape`?

Comment: Anyone reviewing the code, now or in the future, will see that a class with virtual methods has no virtual destructor, and will raise valid concerns. Adding that virtual destructor add very little cost. Anyone who ever refactors this code and wants to add more ways of making instances will be burned. You can marry the class to `make_shape`, for sure: simply make the constructor protected, and befriend the `make_shape` method. But this is painful, as the cache is a singleton. The instances could probably hold a reference to the cache, and help in propagating the cache defined inside of `main`.

Comment: @KubaOber added it.